# How to add ImageJ to list of apps that can access system's camera (or other USB wecams)?

Tags: camera, webcam

[image]I would like to add a program to the list of apps that can access my laptop's camera.  I have a MacBook pro with OS 11.1.  Specifically, I want to use the ImageJ's webcam plugin to control a USB endoscope.  I can get the endoscope to work with PhotoBooth, but I want to use the features in the webcam plugin.  ImageJ just says "No webcam detected" and I can't find a way to add programs to the list of allowed apps in the Security & Privacy settings. I looked through some previous threads and didn't see a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a process to "request" camera access–instead, applications simply try to access the camera. ImageJ need not know about the approval process to try to access the webcam.

You cannot add an app that has never tried to use your camera to this list.